# $_SERVER['TEST'] is giving empty result

Tags: php, apache

From the past two days struggling with this:

From app side they are sending header and in server side I am recieving it as `$_SERVER['HTTP_TEST']` but I am getting empty. Please help me with this .
when i do apache_get_headers() also that header is missing

Comment: Try dumping out the $_SERVER array and learn how the value you expect is different from 'TEST'.

Comment: If you add `X-HEDAER` you can access to it through `HTTP_X_HEADER`.  If it is `TEST` try `HTTP_TEST`